# Simple trigger doesn't work

Tags: mysql, triggers

Hy. I am learning mysql and I have a simple trigger example in my book that doesn't work when I try it

```
create trigger newproduct after insert on products 
for each row select "Product selected";
```

The error is :

```
Error Code: 1415. Not allowed to return a result set from a trigger
```

Why do i get this error? I am using mysql 5.2

Comment: [Google it](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Not+allowed+to+return+a+result+set+from+a+trigger). You can't just SELECT data in a trigger, because there's nowhere for the data to go. You can SELECT INTO, because that actually puts the data somewhere so you can use it. How could you use the raw result set from a trigger? You haven't called it from anything that can accept the returned data... What is this book? Does it not go on to explain that/why this won't work?

Comment: @Dave - good response, inappropriate and abusive acronym.

Comment: @Michael Petrotta I accept that, apologise, and have changed it. Sorry, bad habit from stupid colleagues..

Answer (score 0):

Because you should set data to any var like

```
SET @trigger_var = (select "Product selected");
```